# Mongoose transactions: Only one query executing, the other being ignored without error

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, transactions

I'm trying to test out a very simple transaction involving two updates on the same collection. The idea is, I need both queries to fail if any one of them fails. Here's my code:

```
      const session = await mongoose.startSession();
      session.startTransaction();
      try {
        const opts = { session, new: true };
        const A = await Author.
        findOneAndUpdate({firstName: 'Red'}, {firstName: 'Gray'}, opts);
        const B = await Author.
        findOneAndUpdate({firstName: 'Bill'}, {firstName: 'William'}, opts);
        await session.commitTransaction();
        session.endSession();
      } catch (err) {
        await session.abortTransaction();
        session.endSession();
        throw err;
      }
```

So for the sake of testing, I'm trying to change the `firstName` fields in two separate documents in the same collection. I'm deliberately feeding a false condition in the first `findOneAndUpdate()` (the collection does not have any document with the value `Red` for `firstName`). The second condition is positive. However, while the second query executes, the first one doesn't. And *mongoose* throws no error, nor warning. In a situation like this, I'd like **both** queries to fail, i.e. the transaction to be aborted. How could one accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, [`findAndAndUpdate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) doesn't throw if it's not able to find a document to update. That means that you're not actually calling `session.abortTransaction();`. If you throw when you aren't able to find a document to update, that code should start working the way that you expect.

You may want to write your own wrapper around Mongoose's `findOneAndUpdate` to check whether it successfully updated any documents & to throw if not.